# How to use ParseObject update field?

Tags: php, parse-platform

How to use Extend to update the field?

Example SQL: UPDATE Empresa SET categorias = 'cat_01' WHERE id_user = 'dlkj83d'

```
$query = new ParseQuery('Empresa');
$query->equalTo("users", Session::get('user'));
$query->add("categorias", 'cat_01');   <- ERROR
$query->save();
```

Test

```
$query = new ParseQuery('Empresa');
$query->equalTo("users", Session::get('user'));

$empresa = new ParseObject($query);
$empresa->add('categorias', array('cat_01'));
$empresa->save();
```

Does not work.

:(

Comment: "Does not work." is not a descriptive message. Can you list the errors please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect.

```
    $query = new ParseQuery('Restaurante');
    $query->equalTo("users", Session::get('user'));

    $results = $query->first();
    $results->add('categorias', array('cat_02'));
    $results->save();
```

I still have some difficulties regarding the method NoSQL. Knowing that the reasoning is different.

Thank you for your attention.

You are part of the development team?

Comment: To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such `ParseQuery::add()` function. You are trying to cobble an `UPDATE` into a `SELECT`... you have to first `find()` the resulting `ParseObject`s and iterate through each one:

```
$query = new ParseQuery('Empresa');
$query->equalTo('users', Session::get('user'));
$results = $query->find(); // Returns an array of ParseObjects

foreach ($results as $res) {
    $res->add('categorias', 'cat_01');
    $res->save(); // Make sure you write Exception handling for this in the future
}
```

There is also a [`ParseObject::set` and `setArray`](https://parse.com/docs/php_guide#objects-updating_anchor) function that will achieve the same thing, as `add` may be getting deprecated.

Comment: @mattrepublic The docs are spotty, the [code never lies.](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseObject.php#L840) However, `addArray` doesn't seem to exist anymore, so I'll edit that out.